# Oracle PL/SQL How to store and fetch a dynamic multi column query

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I am trying hard dynamic PL/SQL thing here.
I don't manage to fetch a column dynamic Query.
I am iterating on the name of the column to concatenate a full query in order to be executed on another table.

```
sql_req := 'select '; 
for c in  (SELECT name_col  from TAB_LISTCOL)
loop
  sql_req := sql_req || 'sum(' || c.name_col || '),'; 
end loop; 
sql_req := sql_req || ' from ANOTHER_TAB ';
```

And when i try to execute it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or cursors or INTO/BULK COLLECT thing or just to fetch, i don't manage to iterate on the result. 
I tried a lot. 
Can you help me plz ? Or maybe it is not possible ?

ps : i know the coma is wrong but my code is more complexe than this : i didn't want to put more things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this helps

In the absence of actual table structure and requirement, I'm creating dummy tables and query to illustrate an example:

```
    SQL> create table another_tab
         as
         select 10 dummy_value1, 100 dummy_value2, 1000 dummy_value3 from dual union all
         select 11 dummy_value1, 101 dummy_value2, 1001 dummy_value3 from dual union all
         select 12 dummy_value1, 102 dummy_value2, 1003 dummy_value3 from dual
         ;

    Table created.

    SQL> create table tab_listcol
         as select column_name from dba_tab_cols where table_name = 'ANOTHER_TAB'
         ;

    Table created.
```

To reduce complexity in the final block, I'm defining a function to generate the dynamic sql query. This is based on your example and will need changes according to your actual requirement.

```
    SQL> create or replace function gen_col_based_query 
            return varchar2  
            as
                l_query varchar2(4000);
            begin
                l_query := 'select ';
                for cols in ( select column_name cname from tab_listcol )
                loop
                l_query := l_query || 'sum(' || cols.cname || '), ' ;
                end loop;
                l_query := rtrim(l_query,', ') || ' from another_tab';
                return l_query;
            end;
            /

    Function created.
```

Sample output from the function will be as follows

```
    SQL> select gen_col_based_query as query from dual;

    QUERY
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    select sum(DUMMY_VALUE1), sum(DUMMY_VALUE2), sum(DUMMY_VALUE3) from another_tab
```

Below is a sample block for executing a dynamic cursor using DBMS_SQL. For your ease of understanding, I've added comments wherever possible. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-8DF5B8A3-70F8-4AF5-A747-B1CE6B7D90DF).

```
    SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited

    SQL> declare

            sql_stmt   clob;
            src_cur    sys_refcursor;
            curid      number;
            desctab    dbms_sql.desc_tab;  -- collection type
            colcnt     number;
            namevar    varchar2 (50);
            numvar     number;
            datevar    date;
            l_header   varchar2 (4000);
            l_out_rows varchar2 (4000);

         begin

             /* Generate dynamic sql from the function defined earlier */
             select gen_col_based_query into sql_stmt from dual;


             /* Open cursor variable for this dynamic sql */
             open src_cur for sql_stmt;


             /* To fetch the data, however, you cannot use the cursor variable, since the number of elements fetched is unknown at complile time.
             Therefore you use DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER to convert a REF CURSOR variable to a SQL cursor number which you can then pass to DBMS_SQL subprograms
             */
             curid := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number (src_cur);


             /* Use DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS to describe columns of your dynamic cursor, returning information about each column in an associative array of records viz., desctab. The no. of columns is returned in colcnt variable.
             */
             dbms_sql.describe_columns (curid, colcnt, desctab);


             /* Define columns at runtime based on the data type (number, date or varchar2 - you may add to the list)
             */
             for indx in 1 .. colcnt
             loop
                if desctab (indx).col_type = 2  -- number data type
                then
                   dbms_sql.define_column (curid, indx, numvar);
                elsif desctab (indx).col_type = 12  -- date data type
                then
                   dbms_sql.define_column (curid, indx, datevar);
                else  -- assuming string
                   dbms_sql.define_column (curid, indx, namevar, 100);
                end if;
             end loop;


             /* Print header row */
                 for i in 1 .. desctab.count loop
                  l_header := l_header || ' | ' || rpad(desctab(i).col_name,20);
                 end loop;
                 l_header := l_header || ' | ' ;
                 dbms_output.put_line(l_header);


            /* Loop to retrieve each row of data identified by the dynamic cursor and print output rows
            */

             while dbms_sql.fetch_rows (curid) > 0
             loop
                for indx in 1 .. colcnt
                loop
                   if (desctab (indx).col_type = 2)  -- number data type
                   then
                      dbms_sql.column_value (curid, indx, numvar);
                      l_out_rows := l_out_rows || ' | ' || rpad(numvar,20);
                   elsif (desctab (indx).col_type = 12)  -- date data type
                   then
                      dbms_sql.column_value (curid, indx, datevar);
                      l_out_rows := l_out_rows || ' | ' || rpad(datevar,20);
                   elsif (desctab (indx).col_type = 1)  -- varchar2 data type
                      then
                      dbms_sql.column_value (curid, indx, namevar);
                      l_out_rows := l_out_rows || ' | ' || rpad(namevar,20);
                   end if;
                end loop;
                l_out_rows := l_out_rows || ' | ' ;
                dbms_output.put_line(l_out_rows);
             end loop;

             dbms_sql.close_cursor (curid);
        end;
        /

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Output

```
    | SUM(DUMMY_VALUE1)    | SUM(DUMMY_VALUE2)    | SUM(DUMMY_VALUE3)    |
    | 33                   | 303                  | 3004                 |
```

Comment: OMG its look like you pointed exactly what i wanted ! I will make some time to adapt my code and i return to you if needed !!! Thx a lot

Comment: If this suits your requirement, feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/65088#65088) the answer

Comment: ok i implemented your solution with DBMS_SQL and it works perfectly ! Thx a lot ! I used describe_columns too in order to get back the name of the column and works perfectly too ! I'm really happy

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to get string columns, you can use listagg

```
select listagg(name_col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY null) from TAB_LISTCOL
```

Comment: ho i see ! thx for the tips but it's not the purpose of this question. Once i have my builded query i want to execute it. Execute immediate works but i don't manage to store the result and iterate on the column.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with BULK COLLECT

Below is an example of the same. For more information refer this [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/using-dynamic-sql-for-multirow-queries)

```
    DECLARE
       TYPE name_salary_rt IS RECORD (
          name     VARCHAR2 (1000),
          salary   NUMBER
       );

       TYPE name_salary_aat IS TABLE OF name_salary_rt
          INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

       l_employees   name_salary_aat;
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          q'[select first_name || ' ' || last_name, salary 
               from hr.employees
              order by salary desc]'
          BULK COLLECT INTO l_employees;

       FOR indx IN 1 .. l_employees.COUNT
       LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_employees (indx).name);
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: I saw that post and i tried it but it only works if you know the name of the column and i don't. That's why i go in antoher table to get the name of the column. In this sample, a custom type name_salary_rt is created but i can't create a custom dynamic TYPE

Comment: you can do some conditional processing using DBMS_SQL in the same link.if you provide more details i can help you out

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a query and execute it and return the result to another function or some calling app. As the resulting query's columns are note before-known, I'd return a ref cursor in this case:

```
create function get_sums return sys_refcur as
declare
  my_cursor sys_refcursor;
  v_query varchar2(32757);
begin
  select
    'select ' ||
    listagg('sum(' || name_col || ')', ', ') within group (order by name_col) ||
    ' from another_tab'
  into v_query
  from tab_listcol; 

  open my_cursor for v_query;

  return v_query;
end get_sums;
```

Comment: thx for the help ! I will try it and I come back to you after.